# Improve Grid View display performance in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nscalendar

I have a grid view, and I want to draw rectangles inside each cell of this grid view,

The rectangles here represent an event or reminder, so when I get the reminders and events from native calendar, I filter them to get the events for each day separately so I can draw them in appropriate cell in grid view, but this approach has bad performance.

So how can I draw these events in grid view with excellent performance? How can I avoid the delay generated by filtering events for each day of month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSOperationQueue to do a background process

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming what you are doing now is that you are getting the entire contents of the grid view rectangles simultaneously.

What you can do is to load the grid view rectangles with the events/reminders in a background thread so that you do not jam up the UI while your data is loading. Try using [Apple's Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to do your loading in another thread.

Something along the lines of

```
dispatch_async(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, ^{
        // Your code to get data
    });
```

Comment: also do research Lazy loading.. so that you do not load all the images past the current view..